# Android studio Could not resolve project :sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I hope someone can help me.
I can't start my app on Android Studio because it gives me the following error:

`Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :sdk.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > No matching configuration of project :sdk was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.2.1' but:
> - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.`

how can I solve it? the strange thing is that first it started, after I tried to start it after a while it gave this error.
Thanks!

My settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "OculusReaderandroid"
include ':app',':sdk'
include ':mylibrary'
```

My build.gradle app:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.oltrematica.oculusreader"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs += ['../common/src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs += ['../common/src/main/res']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation project(path: ':sdk')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.3'
}
```

My project structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP8es.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tijl0.png)

Comment: Please share your build.gradle file

Comment: Could you share your settings.gradle file? Please attempt to implement the following code within it::
https://developer.android.com/build#settings-file

Comment: Ok I edit my question with setting.gradle file and build.gradle file

Comment: Android Studio Is Not Able To Find The Module Named "SDK" so please check it carefully or share your project structure image

Comment: @ChiragThummar I open the Project Structure and the sdk module is empty, there is a writing that says "Nothing to show, please select an Android module", but i don't know what I can do

Comment: You can remove ":sdk" from gradle file and try to build it should run the project

Comment: @ChiragThummar if i remove :sdk from gradle file it gives me error, i don't know what i can do :(

Comment: can you please share the screenshot of project structure

Comment: @ChiragThummar i edit my question with the 2 screenshot at the end